# HoloLens: Using Unlit / VertexLit Shaders with Particle System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system, hololens

**Context:** Drawing Graphs on HoloLens via Unity Particle System.

For drawing complex Graphs on Microsoft HoloLens (see my Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073583/5707551) i want to use the VertexLit/Unlit Shaders to increase the frame rate

But if i try to access the color via

```
void Update()
{   
   //...
   for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
   {
      Color c = points[i].GetCurrentColor(GetComponent<ParticleSystem>());
      points[i].startColor = c;
   }
   //...
   GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().SetParticles(points, points.Length);
}
```

with this Shaders the color of the particles does not change.

It worked fine with the default or the FastConfigurable Shader.

Does anyone know what I must consider when using these shaders?

Edit - Shader Properties:

```
Shader "HoloToolkit/Vertex Lit Configurable"
{
    Properties
    {
        [Header(Main Color)]
        [Toggle] _UseColor("Enabled?", Float) = 0
        _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Space(20)]

        [Header(Base(RGB))]
        [Toggle] _UseMainTex("Enabled?", Float) = 1
        _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [Space(20)]

        // Uses UV scale, etc from main texture
        [Header(Emission(RGB))]
        [Toggle] _UseEmissionTex("Enabled?", Float) = 0
        [NoScaleOffset] _EmissionTex("Emission (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [Space(20)]

        [Header(Blend State)]
        [Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode)] _SrcBlend("SrcBlend", Float) = 1 //"One"
        [Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode)] _DstBlend("DestBlend", Float) = 0 //"Zero"
        [Space(20)]

        [Header(Other)]
        [Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode)] _Cull("Cull", Float) = 2 //"Back"
        [Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.CompareFunction)] _ZTest("ZTest", Float) = 4 //"LessEqual"
        [Enum(Off,0,On,1)] _ZWrite("ZWrite", Float) = 1.0 //"On"
        [Enum(UnityEngine.Rendering.ColorWriteMask)] _ColorWriteMask("ColorWriteMask", Float) = 15 //"All"
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "PerformanceChecks" = "False" }
        LOD 100
        Blend[_SrcBlend][_DstBlend]
        ZTest[_ZTest]
        ZWrite[_ZWrite]
        Cull[_Cull]
        ColorMask[_ColorWriteMask]

        Pass
        {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            // We only target the HoloLens (and the Unity editor), so take advantage of shader model 5.
            #pragma target 5.0
            #pragma only_renderers d3d11

            #pragma shader_feature _USECOLOR_ON
            #pragma shader_feature _USEMAINTEX_ON
            #pragma shader_feature _USEEMISSIONTEX_ON
            #pragma multi_compile  __ _NEAR_PLANE_FADE_ON

            #include "HoloToolkitCommon.cginc"
            #include "VertexLitConfigurable.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the shader properties: does it *have* a color multiplier?

Comment: The existing color properties is only "Main Color". But this overwrites the color for all particles inside the particle system. Must i access the color in another way for these shaders?

Comment: According to [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/accessing-_tintcolor-in-particle-fragment-shader.7430/#post-55400) particles and color are a little different. There's a supplied super-basic shader that only handles the color from the particles. See if that works. If it does, you'll have to combine that with whatever else you're doing to get the desired result. Shader programming isn't easy, but sometimes its all you've got.